# Google PanoramaAPI stopped working on Android 11

Tags: android, panoramas, android-11

I have a working implementation of Googles PanoramaAPI in my Application. Unfortunately, the implementation stopped working on Android 11.

The implementation looks like the following:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Panorama.PanoramaApi.loadPanoramaInfoAndGrantAccess(mClient, uri).setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<PanoramaResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PanoramaResult result) {
                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Intent viewerIntent = result.getViewerIntent();
                    Log.i(TAG, "found viewerIntent: " + viewerIntent);
                    if (viewerIntent != null) {
                        startActivity(viewerIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "error: " + result);
                }
            }
        });
```

Following Situation:

- When I make a panorama image on my smartphone and load it into the given implementation, it works. The image get's loaded from `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/*.jpg` and the panorama view is shown without a problem.
- When I Upload the same image on a server and download it through the app, the image get's stored on `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<applicationId>/files/*.jpg`. Unfortunately, the panorama view is not able to load the image and the `viewerIntent` is allways `null`.

For me, it looks like a permission problem on Android 11, but I don't know how to fix it. I don't want to download the image into a more public area of the phone. Does anyone has an idea how to fix it?

Comment: I am facing similar issue with Android 11, where the 360 photo is stored in my external storage. Did you able to fix that yet?

Comment: unfortunately not yet, sorry. It seems like no one else has such a problem

Comment: I am not sure, what else i can do. I tried external and internal file path both. nothing is working. Wondering if there is a new Google API that I need to use.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is related to the introduction of [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) in Android 11, but I'm not sure.

I've managed to put together an alternative to the Panorama API using the VR Kit, which I've documented in my [blog post](https://fieldwire.github.io/android/2021/04/02/360-photo-viewer-on-android-11.html) with some code snippets.

The TLDR is this:

1. Replace your original `ImageView` with a `VrPanoramaView`
2. Use the `VrPanoramaView`'s API to hide some options (optional)
3. Overlay an image button over the `VrPanoramaView` and use it to toggle between gyroscopic and touch modes
4. Use touch interception to support pinch zoom (this will be in a separate blog post)
5. Load your image into `VrPanoramaView`